# Hibernate with multi updating

Tags: java

My project is working with Java Hibernate.
I have a problem like below:

In the case when 2 or more people commit an update statement to the `TBL_USERS` table at the same time.
for example:
They update field: `user_id= 1` at the same time.

I know that if first person can update, others can not.

How i can process that problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Post some source, indicate what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

you can use synchronization concept on the method which call at the time of update.Then at a time one user can update.